# can I mount the same network drive on two PIs

Tags: networking

Could I reliably mount the same network drive on two PIs connected to the same internal network?

At the moment, I have one PI moving pictures from its saved location, to its mounted network drive, linked to a Box account, each time its camera detects movement.

What I'm concerned about is, if I duplicate the above system, I'll have two mounted devices pointed to one external drive; with the possibility of both PIs trying to upload files possibly at the same time.

I'm using davfs2 to mount my network drive and have set up my PI like [this](http://www.sbprojects.com/projects/raspberrypi/webdav.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not particular familiar with davfs2, those filesystem drivers are usually able to allow mounting and using the filesystem from differemt hosts.
Simply adding content to the filesystem as in your use case is a rather uncritical operation. It gets more complicated when one host is modifying a file and another host does or wants to do the same, but even for that problem davfs2 has a solution, see http://dav.SourceForge.net/index.shtml